# Useful environment for CDI / weld web-applications

Tags: tomcat, ejb-3.0, cdi, jboss-weld, jsr299

I am new to weld and consider what environment is useful for a web-application using CDI (Weld). I want to use JSF or Wicket for presentation and JPA/Hibernate for my persistence layer (including Transaction-Management). The obvious scenario is to use a JBoss or Glassfish application server with EJB3 surrounding, but is there not a chance to use tomcat or other “lightweight” servlet-containers in a sensible way? 
Or is it absurd to try to develop a CDI-webapplication without surround of EJB/Seam?
I am interested in some user-experience!

Answer (score 0):

There is the unportable extension [Servlet support](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WeldExtensions#H-ServletSupportUnportableExtensionLedByPeteMuir) for Weld.

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.1-Final/en-US/html/environments.html) you can find how to setup the environment in order to have CDI working on tomcat.

(As a sidenote, I'd share my disappointment that CDI hasn't actually been specified so that it can run in *any* environment. So (as you can see on the above page) many unportable extensions start to appear, and that's exactly what the JBoss guys are accusing spring of)